# Tag information appears below Edit Summary box

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor

The tag information box appears below the Edit Summary box on the editing page for tag wikis (see screenshot below).

[image: Editor tag information bug]

I am using Chrome Canary 19.0.1046.0 on Windows 7 64-bit. You can try and reproduce this for yourself at the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/16927

Comment: browser (+version), os?

Comment: @YannisRizos: Chrome Canary 19.0.1046.0 on Windows 7 64-bit, but I think it's a problem in all browsers.

Comment: [Not officially supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need). However, I'm seeing the bug on Chrome 17.0.963.56 m, which as current stable it should be supported (although the Meta question I linked to says otherwise).

Comment: Reproduced in SeaMonkey 2.6.

Comment: I repro this in Chrome stable 16.0.something, but it looks *slightly* different: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ykNTq.png

Comment: @CodyGray: Wow, strange. I can't even imagine what might cause that.

Comment: @CodyGray: Actually, I'm getting the same thing in Chrome Canary 19 - you can reproduce the original by typing something in the box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in the next build. The CSS correctly defined a `z-index` for the popup, but since we made a change to the popup structure a while ago, it wasn't positioned anymore, rendering the `z-index` useless.

On a side note: When you report bugs, please reproduce them in a released browser; I know it didn't matter in this case, but the canary build (and other dev and beta releases) tend to be full of issues, which is why we're not supporting them. Thanks!